# dragging finger through view and making it works

Tags: android, android-studio

I am doing an activity, in which there will be a View in a center. 
Here is how will it work. When I will be dragging my finger randomly across the screen, this view should make action only when my finger is in bounds of this view.

My code(not correct just want to know if my thinking is correct):

```
firstlayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {


            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                float x = event.getX();
                float y = event.getY();
                if ( (firstlayout.getLeft() <= x <= firstlayout.getRight()) &&
                        (firstlayout.getTop() <= y <= firstlayout.getBottom())
                        )
                {
                    Log.i("A", "Motion Event is currently above firstlayout");
                    firstlayout.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
                }

                return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

There is an error: Operator <= cannot be applied to 'boolean','int'
Please write some code example if you could
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid Java:

```
firstlayout.getLeft() <= x <= firstlayout.getRight()
```

Instead, you must do

```
(firstlayout.getLeft() <= x) && (x <= firstlayout.getRight())
```

Additionally, your view can only receive touch events when that touch occurs within the bounds of the view.  There is no need for you to manually check the bounds.